# How to Add, Edit and Display one to many relationship entities in ASP.Net MVC 2?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I am looking for best practices conforming to the MVC design pattern.

My Entities have the following relationship.
**tblPortal** PortalId PrortalName
**tblPortalAlias** AliasId PortalId HttpAlias

Each Portal can have many PortalAlias.

I want to Add a New Portal and then Add the associated PortalAlias.

**I am confused on how I should structure the Views and how I should present the Views to the user.** I am looking for some sample code on how to accomplish this.

My thoughts are first present the Portal View, let the user add the Portal. Then click the Edit link on the Portal List View and on the Portal Edit View let them Add the PortalAlias.

If so, what should the Edit View look like?

So far I have:

**Edit View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Mvc.Models.PortalFormViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Edit
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2>Edit</h2>
<% Html.RenderPartial("PortalForm", Model); %>
<div>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**PortalForm**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyProject.Mvc.Models.PortalFormViewModel>" %>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

       <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Portal.PortalId) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Portal.PortalId) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Portal.PortalId) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Portal.PortalName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Portal.PortalName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Portal.PortalName) %>
        </div>            
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
Alias<br /><%-- This display is for debug --%>
<% foreach (var item in Model.PortalAlias) { %>

<%= item.HTTPAlias %><br />

<% } %>
```

**PortalFormViewModel**

```
public class PortalFormViewModel
{
    public Portal Portal { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<PortalAlias> PortalAlias { get; private set; }

    public PortalFormViewModel()
    {
        Portal = new Portal();
    }

    public PortalFormViewModel(Portal portal)
    {
        Portal = portal;
        PortalAlias = portal.PortalAlias;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've found an answer to this elsewhere, although based on how difficult it is to find information about this online, it's probably unlikely ...

An MSDN blog linked over to [ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework, Modifying One-to-Many and Many-to-Many Relationships](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/110/ASP.NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-Modifying-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-Many-Relationships) (there's a link to the previous in the series in the first paragraph).

But [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) seems a little better (and includes sample code).

Comment: Steve's Knockout post is an even better way to edit one-to-many relationships. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for the additional link. I thought that example looked familiar, and now I know why. Unfortunate that he didn't link the older to the newer, but ... good find!

Comment: @KasperSkov, I think it might be a GitHub issue. The frame source is http://demo.stevensanderson.com/ko_gift_editor/ which is 404ing for me. But I also got the message in Chrome (in a message box). http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html might be a semi-match. (No email link, and I stopped using Twitter, so I've given up trying to contact Steve about the issue.)

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324837/add-related-entities-with-asp-net-mvc-and-razor) question.